# Delete from table one row with 2 variable with limit

Tags: mysql, mariadb, delete

I'm developing a PHP script who store session of users in a Database.

When an user logout from server, remove only one row ( because same user can login more than one time )

When server reboot, remove all session of all users from that server with same ip.

## Table structure:

- Table name:

  - totalconcurrent
- Column in table:

  - ID [int, autoincrement, 11]
  - serverip [mediumint]
  - userid [text]

Running on :

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

## Case: User logout

Query runs correctly but doesn't delete anything.

```php
    elseif ($_GET['status'] == "logout"){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM totalconcurrent WHERE (serverip,userid) IN ((INET_ATON('".get_server_ip()."'),'".$_GET['id']."')) LIMIT 1;";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "1 Session of ".$_GET['id']." removed";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
```

## Case: Server Reboot

Query runs correctly but doesn't delete anything.

```php
    elseif ($_GET['status'] == "reboot"){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM totalconcurrent WHERE serverip IN ((INET_ATON('".get_server_ip()."')));";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Server rebooted, removed all session stored in this server";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
```

## Problem:

I've tryed many times and many types of query to do this but without finding the correct way to do this.

What queries i need for do this?

Comment: Add final `$sql` variable value for each code block. And show sample data (2-3 records) stored in a table (one of them must be those which must be deleted by the query from `$sql`).

Comment: @Akina What do you mean? I didn't understand correctly.

Comment: You assign some value into `$sql` variable. Dump it and show its value. After all substitutions and insertions.

Comment: Oh you edited the first comment, that's why i was not understanding. Anyway, so the first `$sql` need to be a `select`. Then i'll do a `$sql2` where i select one row to delete and i'll delete that. That's for the case logout. But for reboot? I do a foreach with php? With a foreach doesn't have a good performance.